# Drawing simple pictures in C

Tags: c, loops, parameters

I am new to C and just starting to learn how to use it. 3. I need to write  a program which prompts the user to enter an integer (in the range 1-8) determining picture size and then uses functions which call writePattern to draw each of the following pictures.

I previously created a rectangular "comment" box that I had to make, but these simple drawings are more complex and I am unsure how to do them. I am also new to StackOverflow so I will post my code into a pastebin link rather than putting the code on here because I do not know how to do so properly.

Here is the code I am working on: http://pastebin.com/up7Rg9ZX

As you can see in the code, drawBox, drawSlantRight, drawSlantLeft, drawTriangle, drawX, and drawXmasTree all need to be completed by me. I feel like they probably all have a similar connection as far as doing them. It probably involves a bunch of loops, however I have no idea how to set it up. If someone could show me how just one of these is done, then I feel like I will be able to get the rest. Hope you can help. Heard this was a great website for programming help. Thanks!

Comment: You should try something, and then ask for specific help with a specific question once you have one.

Comment: I have no idea how to set it up. I was told to come to this website for help.

Comment: It's homework, right?  Don't you have a teacher or classmate who can help you?

Comment: Also - there are instructions on the question post/edit page that tell you how to include code with your question.  Including links is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @TuckerSampson ...to come here for help **with specific questions** is perfectly fine, but "how to do my homework" might be a bit too general.  Start with the code you wrote to draw the comment box, and try to modify it to print what is required.  If something doesn't work out, come here to ask specific questions.

Comment: It is not homework. I am working on assignments that I am finding on the internet as I am self-teaching myself C. So I do not have anyone who can help me. I was told by an online user to go on Stack Overflow for help with anything programming-related.

Comment: @TuckerSampson Okay, fair enough, but the main message still applies: first try it yourself and come back with much more specific questions if it doesn't work out. Good luck!

Comment: I thought the users on this website were going to be more helpful than I am seeing so far. This isn't homework! I do not know how to set it up. I just need to see one of these methods completed and I will definitely understand how to do the rest of them! Not much to ask for, I just really need some help...I can't make my question any more specific than it already is.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger I agree with you 100%. I provided the user with one of the functions, just to give him/her an insight. Its up to the user to do the others imo

Comment: @TuckerSampson Whether it's homework or not really isn't the point here (it's just that your question follows a pattern that usually indicates homework). This is a Q&A site for programming problems. While beginner questions are welcome (although most of them probably have already been answered; use the search function if in doubt) we generally don't do "This is a task, please give me the solution" style of problems here, especially if there is no visible effort of the OP to solve them problem him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are classic getting-started functions to get use to working with loops and simple programming logic. Since you have no idea on how to do them, I am gonna show you how to do the first function. You will get an idea on what needs to be done, and I recommend that you try the others out personally. Its the only way you will learn!

```
/* draws a square box with chars '*' and '.'.  For example if the
   parameter value is 3, the following box would be drawn.
   *..
   **.
   ***
*/

    void drawBox(int size)
    {
        int line_counter;
        for (line_counter = 1; line_counter < size+1; line_counter ++)
        {
         int star_counter;
         for (star_counter = 0; star_counter < line_counter; star_counter ++)
         {
          printf("*"); 
         }

         int dot_counter;
         for (dot_counter = line_counter; dot_counter < size; dot_counter ++)
         {
          printf("."); 
         }

        printf("\n");
        }

    }
```

Try that, it should work. So basically there is the gist of it. Like I said, you need to meddle around with for loops, counters and print statements.

Since your getting started I have listed some resources you might be interested in. For a good tutorial on C, try this [site](http://www.iu.hio.no/~mark/CTutorial/CTutorial.html). Furthermore, if you want to invest more in this study, I would highly recommend getting The C [Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628), available at all good book shops (no commercial ad intended). Its co-written by Dennis M. Ritchie (The creator of C).